# Pandas read_csv mixed types columns as string

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any option in pandas' `read_csv` function that can automatically convert every item of an `object` dtype as `str`.

For example, I get the following when trying to read a CSV file:

`mydata = pandas.read_csv(myfile, sep="|", header=None)`

`C:\...\pandas\io\parsers.py:1159: DtypeWarning: Columns (6,635) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  data = self._reader.read(nrows)`

Is there a way such that (i) the warning is suppressed from printing, but (ii) I can capture the warning message in a string from where I can extract the specific columns, e.g. 6 and 635 in this case (so that I can fix the `dtype` subsequently)? Or, alternatively, if I can specify whenever there are `mixed types`, the `read_csv` function should convert the values in that column to `str` ?

I'm using Python 3.4.2 and Pandas 0.15.2

Comment: It is possible to give an extract of the data that reproduces this?

Comment: the data file is quite big, but one of the specific columns has around 5000 rows that have values `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`, and around 1600 rows that have values `Y` (and also the first 3000 rows all have values `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Dtypewarning` is a `Warning` which can be caught and acted on. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) for more information. To catch the warning we need to wrap the execution in a `warnings.catch_warnings` block. The warning message and columns affected can be extracted using `regex`, then used to set the correct column type using `.astype(target_type)`

```
import re
import pandas 
import warnings

myfile = 'your_input_file_here.txt'
target_type = str  # The desired output type

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as ws:
    warnings.simplefilter("always")

    mydata = pandas.read_csv(myfile, sep="|", header=None)
    print("Warnings raised:", ws)
    # We have an error on specific columns, try and load them as string
    for w in ws:
        s = str(w.message)
        print("Warning message:", s)
        match = re.search(r"Columns \(([0-9,]+)\) have mixed types\.", s)
        if match:
            columns = match.group(1).split(',') # Get columns as a list
            columns = [int(c) for c in columns]
            print("Applying %s dtype to columns:" % target_type, columns)
            mydata.iloc[:,columns] = mydata.iloc[:,columns].astype(target_type)
```

The result should be the same `DataFrame` with the problematic columns set to a `str` type. It is worth noting that string columns in a Pandas `DataFrame` are reported as `object`.

Comment: actually, I wanted to avoid reading the `read_csv` twice. I wanted to use the first `read_csv` as it is, but then somehow access the DtypeWarning message printed on the Python console to find the column numbers where there was a warning

Comment: @uday the updated code should do it. However, note that Pandas string columns are reported as `object`. My test input file that produces the same error has all data in the columns showing warnings mapped as `object` already and so the code has no outward effects.  Without seeing your input data it's impossible to know if that's the case for your data too.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the error message itself, the simplest way to avoid `pd.read_csv` from returning mixed dtypes is to set `low_memory=False`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(..., low_memory=False)
```

This luxury is however not available when concatenating multiple dataframes using `pd.concat`.